# Odd spacing in Navigation Bar

Tags: menus, css, navigation

I am in the process of redesigning [my website](http://protechig.staging.wpengine.com), and i'm struggling to find what is causing spacing (margins i'm assuming) between navigation items. I have been delving through chrome developer tools and I cannot find what is causing it anywhere. Note that when you hover between items there is a noticeable white bar between items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That issues is often encountered when using inline-block on elements. Could be fixed with a good CSS reset when starting the theme (may force you to rewrite lots of css sections) or by making the menu "li" elements display block and float left instead. Check my screenshot how I "fixed" your problem.

[image]

[image link](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s98/sh/deabef9e-db64-45cb-b567-e4125b89d369/34675e19a5a535d00972d4baca38634b/res/6556a798-6296-4454-bb8d-daa5e479e7a0/skitch.jpg)

Comment: I am getting "Permission Denied" when clicking the image link (evernote error) I am unable to read your css without that :)

Comment: that is strange, I can see it even in other browsers, not loged in.

here is another link: https://www.evernote.com/shard/s98/sh/deabef9e-db64-45cb-b567-e4125b89d369/34675e19a5a535d00972d4baca38634b

Comment: Nevermind, was able to open images in a new tab. Thanks so much for your help!